# Read XML and show it at an TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ios, tableview

I want to do something very simple - read a XML from the web and then show (in a TableView) the contents of the `titulo` in the xml.

Here's what it looks like:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
  <lista>
  <edicao>
  <ano>2011</ano> 
  <mes>1</mes> 
  <titulo>01/2011</titulo> 
  <file>01-2011.pdf</file> 
  </edicao>
  <edicao>
  <ano>2010</ano> 
  <mes>4</mes> 
  <titulo>04/2010</titulo> 
  <file>04-2010.pdf</file> 
  </edicao>
  </lista>
```

I've searched a lot, but I was unable to find how to do it. Most of the examples already had a class named `XMLParser` that I don't know how to create. I looked at the libraries too, but I just can't find out how to do it. If anyone can advise me how to do this it would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial that shows XML parsing using **GDataXMLParser**.

[how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

GDataXMLParser is better than NSXMLParser since latter is slower.

Answer (score 0):

The Cocoa framework provides an XML parser class called NSXMLParser. You can find out more about it at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSXMLParser.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a great library out there that makes it really easy to parse XML files.

It is called TouchXML and you can find it on github [here](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML).

There are a bunch of tutorials online but is is very easy to use.

[This](http://dblog.com.au/general/iphone-sdk-tutorial-building-an-advanced-rss-reader-using-touchxml-part-1/) is the one I learned with.

Comment: I looked at this, i dont liked because it adds lots of code files to the project and makes it very big while i want to maintain it simple, ill try using the default parser if it gets too complicated ill try this one, thanks

Comment: I have used it in all my projects, classes are plain text files, checking quickly, it adds about 120 kb to your project; I doubt you will even fell the size increase; trust me on this one, it is absolutely worth it.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/
This helped me...Crate .h and .m from the XMLParser.h and .m then just copy paste the code in it. and use the cell creation function as given in example.

Answer (score -1):

Use the NSXMLParser class with the NSXMLParserDelegate methods. You must be init the parser:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.site.com/example.xml"];
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];
```

And use the delegate methods.